# Between two dates and between two times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get orders from between two dates and  where those orders were between 5PM and 6:20 PM.

```
SELECT CREATION_DATE_TIME_STAMP
FROM SHIPMENT_HEADER 
WHERE CREATION_DATE_TIME_STAMP  between '2019-08-01 17:00:00:000'  and '2019-10-31 18:20:000'  AND
      ORDER_TYPE = 'Catalog'
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Creation_Date_Time---2019-08-01 17:03:05.987. This is the date time format we have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need separate conditions on the date and time components.  Date and time functions are notoriously database specific, but something like this:

```
SELECT CREATION_DATE_TIME_STAMP
FROM SHIPMENT_HEADER 
WHERE CREATION_DATE_TIME_STAMP >= '2019-08-01' AND
      CREATION_DATE_TIME_STAMP < '2019-11-01' AND
      CAST(CREATION_DATE_TIME_STAMP as TIME) >= '17:00:00' AND
      CAST(CREATION_DATE_TIME_STAMP as TIME) <= '18:20:00' AND
      ORDER_TYPE = 'Catalog';
```

This assumes that a simple `cast()` is sufficient to extract the time.